# Braid group and knot group

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

It is well known that braid groups and knot groups share many common properties. For example, they have the same $H_1$ and they are both residually finite and (hence) Hopfian. On the other hand, we know that $B_2$ and $B_3$ are isomorphic to the knot groups of unknot and trefoil knot respectively. My question is, for any $n\geq 4$, is there a knot with knot group $B_n$?

If not, how about high dimensional knot $S^n$ in $S^{n+2}$?

Comment: The first question is answered (negatively) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118701/braid-groups-as-knot-groups

Comment: To summarize Igor's link, for $n\ge 4$, $B_n$ contains a copy of $\mathbf{Z}^3$ (use $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_3$, and a generator of the center), while an aspherical 3-manifold group can't contain $\mathbf{Z}^3$ unless it's virtually abelian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple addendum to Danny's answer (because I can't use the citation thing in comments): Homology of braid groups has been computed by a number of people, and [an extensive survey](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.488.4621&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is:

*Vershinin, Vladimir V.*, [**Homology of braid groups and their generalizations**](https://eudml.org/doc/244559), Jones, Vaughan F. R. (ed.) et al., Knot theory. Proceedings of the mini-semester, Warsaw, Poland, July 13--August 17, 1995. Warszawa: Polish Academy of Sciences, Institute of Mathematics, Banach Cent. Publ. 42, 421-446 (1998). [ZBL0905.20032](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0905.20032).

Unless I am misinterpreting the results, there is nontrivial homology in all degrees, so the answer to the OP's second question is negative also.

Answer (score 6):

This is an incomplete answer to the last question, but perhaps someone can supply the last piece of information to complete it. The question of whether a finitely presented group G is a higher-dimensional knot group was resolved by Kervaire. Necessary and sufficient conditions are
(1) G is the normal closure of one element,
(2) $H_1(G) \cong {\mathbb Z}$, and (3) $H_2(G) = 0$.

The first two of these hold for the braid groups. I'm sure that the calculation of $H_2(B_n)$ is somewhere in the literature, but I couldn't locate it.